# Adding another CSS selector to a peusdo selector

Tags: css

I am using one of Chris Coyer's CSS Tricks which works perfect for one table, however I want to implement it on 50 tables

```
table.marin th:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "Rowland Blvd"; }
```

and

```
th.marin:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "Rowland Blvd"; }
```

do not work however the 2nd one works with a p element, but doesn't seem to work with the th element. Any ideas, work-arounds or solutions?

Here is Chris's original [article](https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/) to see exactly what I am doing (hiding the current header and showing a smaller header in mobile view)

Comment: You need to add more details, what have you done, etc

Comment: So what part of it "*doesn't work*"? In *what way* does it "*not work*"? What does it do wrong, what does it not do that it should do?

Comment: What does "2nd one works with a p element" mean? How do you expect us to understand the question if it doesn't have any HTML markup?

Answer (score 0):

Using pseudo elements like `:before` on `th` or `td` would mean, that you insert content before or after it. That could break up the table layout.

To not have cross-browser compatibility issues, I recommend using `div` or `p` containers inside your `th` element and add the pseudo element on that one.

Comment: Actually while I was trying to fix this myself I changed the my code form td to th and when I compared my code to the original CSS Tricks page I noticed the mistake. Once I change my selector from table.marin th:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "Rowland Blvd"; } to table.marin td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "Rowland Blvd"; } it actually worked. My answer was in my own code for table striping: tbody.stripe tr:nth-of-type(2n) {background-color: #F9F9F9;}

Answer (score 0):

Actually while I was trying to fix this myself I changed the my code form td to th and when I compared my code to the original CSS Tricks page I noticed the mistake. Once I change my selector from 
table.marin th:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "Rowland Blvd"; } to table.marin td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "Rowland Blvd"; } 
it actually worked.

My answer was in my own code for table striping: 
tbody.stripe tr:nth-of-type(2n) {background-color: #F9F9F9;}

I also checked the code in Safari, IE10, Firefox latest and Chrome latest, all seem to do well.